# What can I do to get rid of spam emails that come from different, randomized email addresses?

Tags: spam, email-spoofing

Here's an example of the address they're coming from:
[image]

I'm familiar with filtering settings, but how can I filter something that's different each time?

Comment: The commercial spam filtering market is an [850 million dollar](https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2019/02/18/1733713/0/en/Global-Enterprise-Spam-Filter-Market-Will-Reach-USD-2-675-Million-By-2026-Zion-Market-Research.html) industry. If one could hand-craft a simple set of rules to filter out all spam, there would not be such a huge industry around it. You might be able to write rules that filter out some specific spam template that you're getting *at the moment*, but it likely will not work reliably over the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post's body asks about filters. "Filters" require some sort of a match, even a partial one. If there is nothing to match, then filtering is not an effective tool.

But your title asks to "get rid of", and that's a broader goal. If you cannot filter based on sender, then you detect spam by the contents. There are a host of tools and approaches to detect and respond to spam emails:

- inspect attachments and links for malicious or blocked content
- inspect the content of the message body for common or malicious content
- inspect the content of the message body for anomalous content

There is a massive industry around and a thousand approaches to the above.

It is trivial for spammers/phishers to send a million emails from a million different, unrelated sources. Trying to block each one is like playing "whack-a-mole".

Looking at what they send is the more effective approach.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't thought about this route but I've made more progress here than by anything else. I appreciate your time. I also noticed they were being sent to rotating domains, meaning <username>@<domain>; where the <username> is the same but the domain would be aol.com, apple.com etc. Is that part of their bot algorithm to walk through all possible domains? @schroeder

Answer (score 0):

The apparent "**FROM**" is readily faked. Look at the full email headers for several of the spams, odds are good there is a common identifier buried inside that you can use as a filter, it may even be as simple as the originating IP.

Don't forget that your filter need not be an *EQUAL* match. You may find that a substring match using *CONTAINS* will work best.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any clear-cut method, but you could:-

- Use your intuition.If the sender's address seems sketchy(either the apparent randomness in the e-mail address or the obscurity in the domain name) or the e-mail is simply from someone who you don't know.
- You could allocate an hour or two for a one-time organisation of your mailbox,maybe creating subfolders for different purposes such as one for your newsletters, one for e-mails from your colleagues etc. , so that any e-mail you receive that does not automatically fit into these subgroups can be treated as spam.
- (A radical one,but depends on a lot of factors such as your profession and visibility) Create a new e-mail address and jot off a text/e-mail to your associates about the change,then abandon the current one.

(I'm assuming that your e-mail may have been exposed in breaches,making it impossible to avoid spam)